# Improving approach on gcd

Tags: java, algorithm

> You are given an array A of integers of size N. You will be given Q queries where each query is represented by two integers L, R. You have to find the gcd(Greatest Common Divisor) of the array after excluding the part from range L to R inclusive  `N ≤ 10^6, 1 ≤ Q ≤ N,`

My approach:

Calculate The Prefix GCD and Then Suffix GCD and return the answer.

Code:

```java
public static int gcd(int a , int b){
    
    
    if(b==0) return a;
    
    return gcd(b,a%b);
}

for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        
        pre[i] = gcd(a[i],pre[i-1]);
    }
    suff[n]=a[n];
    for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--){
        
        suff[i] = gcd(a[i],suff[i+1]);
        
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        int l = in.nextInt();
        int r =in.nextInt();
        if(r!=n)
        System.out.println(gcd(pre[l-1],suff[r+1]));
        else
            System.out.println(pre[l-1]);
    }
```

Problem :

This approach give me a TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED Error. How can I improve my solution?

Comment: Question is related to on going codechef long contest so please do not post answer

Answer (score 0):

This looks roughly right to me, but it does do a lot of work with some queries. Suppose that the Q queries you're given all have L set to 0; in that case, you won't need any of your prefix calculations. Or suppose there's only 1 query: you're calculating more prefixes and suffixes than you need.

I'd start by looping over the Q queries and finding the min value of R and the max value of L. That will enable you just to calculate the prefixes and suffixes that you will need to answer these queries.

The other potential area for speedup is in your `gcd` function, which you haven't shown us.

By the way, your code currently doesn't work when L is 0. It will try to examine `pre[-1]`.

EDIT: `gcd` looks fine.

Comment: `gcd` function has been added

Answer (score 0):

Let us create two arrays `arr` and `brr` of size `N`. Where `arr[i]` will store the gcd of all the numbers in the input array up to the index `i` (including `i`) and `brr[i]` will store the gcd of all the numbers in the input array after index `i` including `i`.

Example: `arr[3]=gcd(A[0],A[1],A[2],A[3])` and similarly `brr` will be initialized from opposite direction.

Now suppose the query is `3,5` you can simply output `gcd(arr[3],brr[5])`.